# Issue with creating certificate request through MQ runmqckm

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm trying to create certificate request through below command line and returned with error:

```
./runmqckm -certreq -create -db 
/var/mqm/qmgrs/QMGR01/ssl/sslreceiver.kdb -pw password123 -label 
ibmwebspheremqsslreceiver -dn "CN=SSLCLIENT,O=IBMIBM,C=US" -file 
/var/mqm/sslreceiverreq.arm

 The keystore already contains an entry with label
'ibmwebspheremqsslreceiver'.

 Choose a different label and try again.
```

However, there is no such entry as **ibmwebspheremqsslreceiver** in my current keystore file,

```
**@/usr/mqm/bin $ ./runmqckm -cert -list -db
/var/mqm/qmgrs/QMGR01/ssl/sslreceiver.kdb -pw password123 
Certificates in database /var/mqm/qmgrs/QMGR01/ssl/sslreceiver.kdb:    
ssl_ca
```

So why this happened?

Comment: For those that have access to MQ Explorer: Start IBM/WebSphere MQ Explorer. In the Navigator view, right-click IBM/WebSphere MQ, then click Manage SSL Certificates, open a key database file, enter password, ... [ref](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_ssl_ikeymangui.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The first command creates a certificate request.
The second command lists certificates.

If you want to list certificate *requests*, use the `-certreq -list` command instead of the `-cert -list` command.